# How to generate increasing sequence in ScalaCheck?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm trying to generate sequence of increasing numbers using ScalaCheck.

I would like to achieve something like this:

`0 2 4 6`

Which was achieved by increasing range 0..3 by step of 2:

```
0 * 2 = 0
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 2 = 6
```

Thanks for help.
Sorry if question has been questioned before.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use ScalaCheck generators instead of plain Scala range, like `0 to 6 by 2`?

Comment: Well I come across project where property based testing been using, so just learning ScalaCheck to test my code.

Comment: ScalaCheck generators usually generate some random input data. Generating complete and predictable sequence of inputs with them is something I do not remember to have seen and I do not think it is an intended use, therefore the code for this may be far from straightforward.

Comment: I see, thanks for explanation. I think question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it appears not so difficult to generate random sequence. Sorry I needed to be more specific about predictability.

```
object GenerateSequence {

  def apply(maxSize: Int, maxStep: Int): Gen[Seq[Int]] = {
    for {
      size <- Gen.chooseNum(1, maxSize)
      step <- Gen.chooseNum(1, maxStep)
    } yield {
      (0 to size).map(_ * step)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really using `ScalaCheck`, but you can use the stream of `even` numbers:

```scala
>val even = Stream.from(0,2)

>even.take(4)
// Display
// res2: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, 2, 4, 6)
```